# How can I manage pm2 remotely (through network)?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I would like to manage node [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) remotely (through network), is it possible?

Comment: One way is using http://pm2.keymetrics.io/ it's free for one server.

Comment: I think @Molda means [keymetrics](https://keymetrics.io/) (the link is pointing to [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io)), which i'd say is the best option if you are ok with one server. There's of course always the option of writing a tiny service and letting it manage pm2 since [you can use pm2 programmatically](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/)

Comment: Sure i did @cviejo thanks for correcting.